# Layered window still receiving WM_PAINT message after UpdateLayeredWindow call

Tags: windows, user-interface, layered-windows

I've got a few layered windows in my app that use [`UpdateLayeredWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633556(VS.85).aspx) to handle their visual representation.  According to the [MSDN article on layered windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx), "when using `UpdateLayeredWindow()` the application doesn't need to respond to `WM_PAINT` or other painting messages."  They shared some of the same message handlers as non-layered windows, so I figured I would just return early from `WM_PAINT` handling if the target is a layered window.

Of course, this caused one major issue: if one of the layered windows *did* get a `WM_PAINT` message, the input queue would end up flooded with an unending stream of `WM_PAINT` messages.  This end-result makes sense, since the window would never be validated and so it will keep thinking it needs to paint (I shouldn't be returning from the handler without validating or `BeginPaint()`ing, etc.), but what *doesn't* make sense is why it received the message in the first place, since it has no effect on a window that was using `UpdateLayeredWindow()`.

It wouldn't even happen reliably -- just every now and then, and not every time the window's pixels needed redrawing.  Sanity was restored by falling back to `DefWindowProc()` when a layered window got a `WM_PAINT` message, but I feel like something is going on that I don't understand.  And considering how seldom this problem manifested itself, I'm worried this might just be hiding an even subtler problem.  Is it expected behavior for a window using `UpdateLayeredWindow()` to still get the occasional `WM_PAINT` message?  Does it matter, as long as I handle it correctly?

Additional info, if needed: the window is calling `UpdateLayeredWindow()` immediately after being created, and then it's left on its own (it doesn't call it again, since it doesn't change).  Using C++ and win32 API, no MFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had run into similar issues before, although my memory may be a bit rusty by now.

First off, keep the DefWindowProc. When the docs say you don't have to respond, I would take that to mean to ignore the message entirely, rather than prevent default handling.

I personally experienced this from two different causes. One was a window which was actually sending WM_PAINT messages (evil! beware!). The other (IIRC) resulted from certain RedrawWindow calls. In both cases, I chalked the problem up to poorly written code, outside of my control, and never had any situations arise from simply passing it down to DefWindowProc.

Hopefully you will have the same experience!

Good luck. I found layered windows to be poorly documented and full of interesting caveats and gotchas, but very pleasing once you get all the kinks worked out.